# "Gis:property-value primitive" netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am using the gis extension in netlogo. I got stuck in this point:

Using the primitive `gis:property-value`

The line of code looks like this:

```
gis:set-drawing-color scale-color red (gis:property-value ? "POPULATION") 5000000 1000
```

I do not know what  `population` and `5000000 1000` means , I mean I assign that name (population) and values (5000000 1000) or they are values that are already written in the .shp file.

Comment: Some of the code appears to be missing. Can you give more context?

Comment: I took that code from the general example made by Wilensky. Have you ever seen it.

Comment: ah, the GIS General Examples model, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

Comment: I have edited your question to include more of the relevant code. The crucial missing part was the call to `scale-color`. Now the question makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

"POPULATION" refers to something that already exists in the .shp file. I imagine it would show up if you browsed the contents of the file using standard GIS tools.

As for `5000000 1000`, these are inputs to the `scale-color` primitive, to translate a range of population values to a range of shades of red. See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#scale-color , and see also the Scale-color Example model in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

The number 500000 was apparently chosen by the model author based on their prior knowledge of the range of population values they expect to appear in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

according to [gis-extension manual](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html#gis:property-value) `gis:property-value` is used like `gis:property-value VectorFeature property-name` to with this small peace of code, I guess your in a foreach loop. The `?` is the shp ID in the loop for the "POPULATION" column and 5000000 1000 seem to be the value for this polygon!

Comment: 5000000 1000 are values for scale-color